# Expo tunnel while running on physical ios device doesnt fast refesh

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using React Native with expo running on VS code and I'm testsing on physical devices. I have both Android and IOS devices. The problem is that although the Android device makes fast refresh when I'm making changes in the code, The IOS device isn't (Fast refresh enabled). Anyone knows what could be the problem?

When Im enabling fast refresh on iOS, I have an error: "The operation couldn't be completed. No route to host".